# How can I have a sub that accepts a variable as byref without declaring what type of variable it is?

Tags: vb.net

How can I have a sub that accepts a variable as byref without declaring what type of variable it is (it could be int, string, etc.) but still have some of the other parameters defined?

I want a sub like this:

```
Private Sub example(ByRef variable, ByRef reader as MySqlDataReader, ByVal columnName as String)
```

Comment: `reader` definitely should not be `ByRef`, and `variable` probably should not be `ByRef`.

Comment: Post your real code.  Your snippet is *way* too fake to give you good advice.

Answer (score 4):

You can make a generic method:

```
Private Sub Example(Of T)(ByRef variable As T, ByRef reader as MySqlDataReader, ByVal columnName as String)
```